# gcc 4.5.1 vs VC2010 template partial specialization: which is C++0x conformant?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, gcc, c++11

The following compiles with VC2010 but fails with gcc 4.5.1 with *-std=c++0x*:

```
template <class T, class TBase>
class TestBase : public TBase
{
public:
// Helper functor
    template <unsigned int t_u, class TRet = int>
    struct Helper
    {
        TRet operator() (int x = 0, int y = 0)
        {
                return (TRet)t_u;
        }
    };
}; // class TestBase

template<class TBase>
class Test0 : public TestBase<Test0<TBase>, TBase>
{
public:
    Helper<100> Get100; // gcc 4.5.1 error: 'Helper' does not name a type
};
```

gcc accepts the more verbose:

```
template<class TBase>
class Test1 : public TestBase<Test1<TBase>, TBase>
{
    typedef TestBase<Test1<TBase>, TBase> thisBase;
public:
    typename thisBase::template Helper<100> Get100;
};
```

Which (if any) is c++0x conformant?

Comment: whenever templates are involved, VC++ is unfortunately not standard compliant. It's annoying, but you soon get the hang of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code snippet, Helper is not a dependent name.  Because it's not dependent, it must be resolved when the template is parsed rather than when it is instantiated.  This is required both in C++03 and C++0x.

Using the typedef makes it a dependent name so it is resolved on instantiation.  You could also use typename Test1::template Helper<100>.

Comment: Thanks. As I have around 20 TestX classes, each having between 10 and 60 Helper<> members, I look for simple declarations. Guess some macro needed ...